# Return only the top row for each join

Tags: sql

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    u.UserName, s.StatusName
FROM 
    UserStatus us
    JOIN Status s on s.StatusId = us.StatusID
    JOIN Users u on u.UserId = us.UserId
WHERE 
    us.UserId in (select UserId from Users)
    AND us.DateCreated > '2017-07-14 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY 
    us.DateCreated desc
```

It returns this:

[image]

How would I get only the most recent status for each user?

**EDIT:**

I can't just do `SELECT TOP 2` because I don't know how many users there are going to be.  There might be 500.  There might be 10.

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in the where that the Date Created is max per user 
Like this

```
SELECT 
    u.UserName, s.StatusName
FROM 
   UserStatus us
    JOIN Status s on s.StatusId = us.StatusID
    JOIN Users u on u.UserId = us.UserId
WHERE 
    us.UserId in (select UserId from Users)
    AND us.DateCreated = (SELECT MAX(DateCreated) FROM UserStatus us2 WHERE 
 us2.UserId = us.UserId)
ORDER BY 
    us.DateCreated desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`SELECT
     u.UserName, s.StatusName`

to

`SELECT TOP(2)
     u.UserName, s.StatusName`

That should select only the top two rows!
See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Edit: If the top rows changes, maybe select based on a percentage of total statuses

Comment: Sorry my OP wording was not very clear.  I edited it.

Comment: TOP will not work. In this case I happen to know that there are only 2 users, so SELECT TOP 2 would work. But that won't always be the case.  See the edits to my OP

Comment: Gotcha. Guess I should have figured your initial question wasn't so straightforward. Don't think my edit will help you, because they can be in the same status in multiple fields...